# jQuery; ONLY grabbing .text() from DOM occurs TWICE

Tags: jquery

I have looked at the other posts from people who have had similar problems, however, none of the scenarios and causes sees to fit this problem.
I am simply getting text from the DOM and console logging it, but it is doubled-up, apended to itself, or something:

123

var showContent = $('#someid').text()
console.log('Results: ' + showContent);

*Displays: 123123*

I have **tried using ).one**, I have **unbound and re-bound the handler**, I have c**hecked for duplicate ID's**, I have **looked at the code for anything looping for a function within iterated code**, but nothing seems to be causing this problem.

The handler itself runs ONCE. (ie; it console logs only one time) and it is not within any kind of loop or iteration or function.

```
<script>
    $('#body').one('click.GET_TTL_DEMO','input#GET_TTL_DEMO', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var demoTotal = $('span#leftQuoteStatTotal').text();
        alert('Just grabbed: $' + demoTotal + ' from the DOM.');
    });
</script>
```

**The only suspect I may have** is that I am aliasing a newer version of jQuery since the bulk software uses the old version so I can get Promises and such. I am in strict mode. This all worked fine until I was called away for 2 months and came back to it.

It may be that someone has changed something higher up the hierarchy (this is a web app within an existing website basically, which has to be drilled down to get to.) but when asked both the other 2 developers say nothing was changed that would affect this.

**Any ideas as to WHY everything else runs once just fine, but ONLY the retrieval of content from the DOM using .text() runs TWICE??**

Thanks!

Comment: What is the HTML markup of the element? Double text on the name line in the  console is not going to be from events bound twice.

Comment: You need to show us your HTML - but it looks like you are overcomplicating this with your selectors etc...

Comment: <span id="leftQuoteStatTotal">4224.00</span>

Comment: That shows me a result of: 4224.004224.00

Comment: This is happening THROUGHOUT the code, not just for this total amount span. It is happening whenever I grab .text() from the DOM. In an entirely other functionality, when choosing to Save a "template", the grabbed data shows double the text, so strings of numbers go from 1 to 11, or 3 to 33, for example. I have created a .one click to grab and alert a result, same thing, doubled text.

Comment: Are you including local Jquery? If so, try using CDN version. Anyway, have you any link to share where this issue can be checked?

Comment: Yes I am, and because it is a newer version I am using: <script type="text/javascript">var $ = $.noConflict(true);</script>

Comment: Same results with a CDN version of jQuery 2.1.4 A. Wolf

Comment: But are you sure `$.fn.text()` is not overriden by some code?

Comment: Co-worker reproduces same thing, we are both on Chrome.

Comment: A. Wolf, no, I am not, as I am working inside of other code. I am not even sure how I would go about checking for it except to search all files for "text()", any suggestions?

Comment: probably not an issue but you have a div called `#body` as well as the `body` tag?

Comment: They are the same in console. Checking the elements... (Yes, Sam0, I can change to document but still no difference)

Comment: Does not appear to be nested, and nothing is concatenating that I can tell at least code wise.

Comment: <div class="leftQuoteStat"><strong>$</strong><span id="leftQuoteStatTotal">0.00</span></div>

Comment: I can look at the DOM Elements and SEE that the text is just the single entry. It is only when I call .text() that it gets doubled, even in a newly declared variable, no append at all. Crazy.

Comment: And doesn't `console.log($('span#leftQuoteStatTotal').length)` returns `2`?  Meaning are you sure you don't have duplicate IDs? FYI, won't happen using `console.log($('#leftQuoteStatTotal').length)`. EDIT: after some testing, i'm quite sure you have duplicate IDs

Comment: Trying that now...

Comment: The culprit ended up being a test failing prior to appending elements. So it WAS a duplicate ID and you, Sir, were entirely correct, A. Wolf ^5 Kudos and Thanx!!! I changed the test to look for undefined type before appending, and all went back to what passes for normal. ^5 :) Length didn't help but went for suspected Appends.

Comment: When working in a primitive environment with other coders and spoonfed info, it was bound to happen, A. Wolff ^5 Spot on. Indeed it was a duplicate ID wrenching the works.